# prove that $M$ is Noetherian if and only if $M'$ and $M''$ are Noetherian.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, proof-explanation, exact-sequence

> Let $0\to M'\xrightarrow{f} M\xrightarrow{g}M''\to0$ be an exact sequence in $A$-module. Then prove that $M$ is Noetherian if and only if $M'$ and $M''$ are Noetherian.

I've a proof from a book as follows :[image]

I'm unable to understand only two line of this proof :

> (1) $g^{-1}(N'')$ and $N''$ are not isomorphic. So why $g^{-1}(N'')$  is finitely generated implies $N''$ is finitely generated ?
>
> (2) In the converse part of the proof why $f^{-1}(N)$ exists ? As the sequence is exact so $f$ is one-one only.

Comment: If $M'$ was just a sub module of $M$, then $f^{-1}(N)$ would be $N \cap M'$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. That is because $g$ is *onto*, hence the restriction of $g$ to $g^{-1}(N'')$ and $N''$ is too.
2. Being one-to-one doesn't preclude the existence of $f^{-1}(N)$: it's not empty, as it contains $0$.

Comment: 1. You mean restriction of $g$  from $g^{-1}(N'')$ to $N''$ becomes an isomorphism. Right ?

Comment: No, it's only surjective.

Comment: Ohh..yes..got it..But still not getting 2.

Comment: My question is actually "Why $f^{-1}(N)$ exists ?

Comment: The inverse image of a subset by any map always exists, and it has nothing to do with modules. I don't see your point. Why shouldn't t exist?